# Как проверить ссылку по шаблону?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, ссылки, re

Есть список ссылок:

```
a = ['abc.ru/v2', 'abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348', 'abc.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348', 'bcd.ru/467', 'abc.com/feed?app_id=57655'
```

Как из этого списка с помощью регулярного выражения вытянуть только эти ссылки:

```
['abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348', 'abc.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348']
```

Пока что есть только часть регулярки, может ее можно как-то дополнить:

```
r'''(?:abc\.com\/)(title/\d{5})'''
```

Comment: А какие особенности ссылок? У них домен abc.com и оканчиваются на /title/<число на 5 цифр>?

Comment: В данной постановке достаточно проверять, что ссылка начинается на `abc.com`, нужно больше пояснений.

Comment: @CrazyElf. добавила еще пример ссылки 'abc.com/feed?app_id=57655', которая не должна попасть в итоговый список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с таким шаблоном `abc\.com/.+/title/\d{5}` (если цифр в числах не 5: `abc\.com/.+/title/\d+`)

```
urls = ['abc.ru/v2', 'abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348', 'abc.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348', 'bcd.ru/467', 'abc.com/feed?app_id=77625']
urls = [url for url in urls if re.search(r'abc\.com/.+/title/\d{5}', url)]
print(urls)
# ['abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348', 'abc.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348']
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы после первого / могли быть только буквы, цифры и точка? то есть если добавить в исходный список 'abc.com/feed?app_id=77625', то такая ссылка тоже подойдет под регулярку, но это не нужно

Comment: А вы не рассматривали вариант со scheme в urllib модуле?

Comment: я знаю про эту библиотеку, но хотелось бы решить задачу  именно с регулярным выражением

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, с чего это она подойдет? В регулярке должно быть `/title/<число>`. Да и после первого `/` у вас `er.tyre.6` (`abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348`) и `test` (`abc.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348`), что тоже не соответствует условию в вопросе

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, а если отвечая на ваш вопрос, то, думаю примерно так: `/[a-zA-Z\d.]+`

Comment: @gil9red, не срабатывает. нужно чтоб ссылки, в которых есть знаки [=?%] игнорировались. через ([^_?%=]+) тоже не получается отбросить такие ссылки

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева, добавил еще условие: `urls = [url for url in urls if re.search(r'abc\.com/.+/title/\d{5}', url) and not re.search(r'\?\w+=\d+', url)]`. Второй вариант, надежнее - нужно через `from urllib.parse import urlparse` парсить ссылки и проверять `urlparse(url).query` - именно там и будут параметры в ссылке